# Double import of index.js and index.msj in Internal/svelte

Tags: webpack, svelte

In svelte preexisting project on svelte, I could observe, with webpack_bundle_analyzer, we have a double import of svelte. One js and an other width mjs. However, the index.js is for me useless indeed, this file is used only in common.js environnment. In the browser, we don't need it. But I don't how to fix this issue.

[webpack_bundle_analyser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vFze0.jpg)